# create sparse matrix all with the element 2

Tags: matlab

I know this is not good use of sparse matrix. But I just want to know what are some efficient ways to create sparse matrix all with the element 2, without creating a full matrix first and converting it to sparse.

From `S = sparse(i,j,s,m,n)` and matlab documentation, I only know how to create diagonal sparse matrix with same element. But do know know how to create all entries with same elements.

Comment: Like `n=10; A = sparse(n,n) + sparse(2);`?

Comment: @TroyHaskin thanks.